# What's idiom/best practice with UncheckedIOException and Stream API?

Tags: java, lambda, java-8

Java 8 officially introduce [`java.io.UncheckedIOException`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/io/UncheckedIOException.html) to JDK class libraries for lambda with Stream API, because lambda expressions can't declare its `throws`-clause and lambda body can't throw checked exception such as `IOException`.

What's idiom/best practice with `UncheckedIOException` and Stream API? What conditions do I explicitly throw new `UncheckedIOException` object, and when should I catch `UncheckedIOException` exception?

Comment: Related: http://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/44392/combining-contents-of-files-by-reading-them-in-a-human-ordering/44401#44401

Comment: minor point - lambdas certainly can throw `IOException`s, but only if the interface method they are representing does so as well.

Comment: @aepurniet Thanks your point, I implicitly presumed functional interface that has no throws-clause, such as `java.util.function.Consumer<T>` for `Stream#forEach()`...

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You would throw it in the same circumstances as the library methods (`BufferedReader.lines` and `Files.lines`) that currently do it: that is, when you are wrapping an I/O exception resulting from  an operation subsequent to opening a file (file opening operations still throw IOException). As for catching it, that depends on your strategy for IO error recovery: in other words, do whatever you do to handle the wrapped IOException in non-stream code.

Comment: IMO, regardless of the strategy for IO error recovery, it seems reasonable to catch/unwrap `UncheckedIOException` ASAP and rethrow as checked exception(`IOException`) within Stream API caller method. What do you think of this point?

Comment: @yohjp yes, catch/unwrap the unchecked exception from the stream code, then rethrow as `IOException` if that is what your method would do anyway, or else handle the `IOException` if that is what your method would do. PS. Is the answer accepted?